# Enable Add To Cart Button If 1 Out Of 3 Variation is not selected

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I am working on product variation in e-commerce . I have three variation in all of my product so i want user to choose two out of three variation from it . So the issue is woo-commerce is disabling add to cart button if all of the three variation is not selected . So can i enable add to cart button considering two variations are selected instead of two ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the standard function of Woocommerce to disable the button until all conditions are met.

As a work around you can create a custom field and hook it into the .variations div.

You might need to do some conditional statements to make sure it does not show on products where it is not needed.